# Why is this panel not working?

Tags: jquery

Have a look at this code here, as you will see I'm just doing a bit of practice with jQuery and trying to build a tab panel.

I got stuck on trying to get the sections to move out of the way once i clicked on a new section.

I have no idea why this is not working for me like this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="buttons">
    <a href="" class="active_button" data-sectionId="section1">Section 1</a>
    <a href="" data-sectionId="section2">Section 2</a>
    <a href="" data-sectionId="section3">Section 3</a>
    <a href="" data-sectionId="section4">Section 4</a>
  </div>

  <div class="sections">

    <div class="section active_section" id="section1">
      Section 1 <br>
      Section 1 <br>
      Section 1 <br>
      Section 1 <br><br>
    </div>

     <div class="section" id="section2">
      Section 2 <br>
      Section 2 <br>
      Section 2 <br>
      Section 2 <br> <br>
    </div>

     <div class="section" id="section3">
      Section 3 <br>
      Section 3 <br>
      Section 3 <br>
      Section 3 <br><br>
    </div>

     <div class="section" id="section4">
      Section 4 <br> 
      Section 4 <br>
      Section 4 <br>
      Section 4 <br><br>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

sass

```
body
  text-align: center
  padding-top: 50px

a
  color: white
  text-decoration: none
  padding: 10px
  background-color: grey
  margin: 0px -1px
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out
  &:hover
    background-color: lightgrey

.active_button
  background-color: lightgrey

.sections
  position: relative

.section
  display: none
  padding: 20px
  background-color: lightgrey
  position: absolute
  width: 286px
  top: 10px
  left: 50%
  margin-left: -163px
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px

.active_section
  display: block
```

jquery

```
$(function() {

  // capture click of section button
  $("a").click(function(e) {

    // prevent default link behaviour
    e.preventDefault();

     // hide the current active section 
    $(".section .active_section").slideUp(500, function(){
      // then take away their active class
      $(this).removeClass("active_section");
    });

  }); // click function closes here


  // find out what section button is pressed
  var sectionId = $("a").attr("data-sectionId");


  // slide down that section
  $("#"+sectionId).slideDown(500, function(){
    // add the active class
    $(this).addClass("active_section");
  });

});
```

Comment: what is happening when you click?

Comment: When you write $('.section .activeSection') - this means that select an element with class active section which is a child of an element with class section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move all your code to the click function, and it's work ;)

https://jsfiddle.net/pgytuq6j/

```
// capture click of section button
$("a").click(function(e) {

    // prevent default link behaviour
    e.preventDefault();

    // find out what section button is pressed
    var sectionId = $(this).attr("data-sectionId");

    // hide the current active section 
    $(".active_section").slideUp(500, function(){
        // then take away their active class
        $(this).removeClass("active_section");
    });

    // slide down that section
    $("#"+sectionId).slideDown(500, function(){
        // add the active class
        $(this).addClass("active_section");
    });

}); // click function closes here
```

This is what you want ?

Answer (score 2):

please check this

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/k2v06bnv/][1]
```

small problems in the code , you have to be more careful about small things

Answer (score 1):

When you write `$('.section .activeSection')` - this means that select an element with class activeSection which is a child of an element with class section. Also the whole code should be inside the click event:

```
$("a").click(function (e) {

    // prevent default link behaviour
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentAnchor = $(this);
    // hide the current active section 
    $(".active_section").slideUp(500, function () {
        // then take away their active class
        $(this).removeClass("active_section");
        $('.active_button').removeClass('active_button');
        $(currentAnchor).addClass('active_button');
    });

    // find out what section button is pressed
    var sectionId = $(this).attr("data-sectionId");

    console.log(sectionId);
    // slide down that section
    $("#" + sectionId).slideDown(500, function () {
        // add the active class
        $(this).addClass("active_section");

    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/hz9t7z9o/)

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/7fp8jq3g/)**

Check the inline comments for JS

**Updated JS**

```
$(function() {
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".section.active_section").slideUp(500, function(){
            $(this).removeClass("active_section");
        });
        //You need to identify clicked element inside click event itself
        //get the sectionId of clicked element using $(this)
        var sectionId = $(this).attr("data-sectionId");
        $("#"+sectionId).slideDown(500, function(){
            $(this).addClass("active_section");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/GaganJaura/yd54d00s/)

The below function will give you smooth transition while sliding up and down

```
$(function() {
  // capture click of section button
  $("a").click(function(e) {

    // prevent default link behaviour
    e.preventDefault();

     // hide the current active section 
    $(".active_section").slideUp(500, function(){        
      // then take away their active class
      $(this).removeClass("active_section");        
        // find out what section button is pressed  
    });

    var sectionId = $(this).attr("data-sectionId");

    setTimeout(function() {
        // slide down that section
        $("#"+sectionId).slideDown(500, function(){
            // add the active class
            $(this).addClass("active_section");
        });
      }, 500);      
  }); // click function closes here  
});
```